# Model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[N]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'N'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
var model = from m in db.Customers
            orderby m.a descending
            select new Get_Complaint_Form_Sub
            {
                CustomerFullName = m.a,
                Email = m.Email_Address,
                PhoneNumber = m.Telephone_No
            };
```

I am using this `LINQ` query to retrieve selected columns in db. It fetches the last record in the table in descending order

Comment: Sorry, i am new to LINQ query. Still learning. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any mention of dictionary in your code, but you mention it in question title

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem here is *downstream*, i.e. something that is *consuming* model. In particular, it sounds like it is expecting **one** `N`, not a query of them. So... you might want to add `.SingleOrDefault()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`, `.Single()` or `.First()` to your query (depending on what you intended). For example:

```
var query = from m in db.Customers
        orderby m.a descending
        select new Get_Complaint_Form_Sub
        {
            CustomerFullName = m.a,
            Email = m.Email_Address,
            PhoneNumber = m.Telephone_No
        };
var model = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

As a more general note: an `IQueryable<T>` *is usually a pending query* - it hasn't been executed yet. Most times that you are talking about a *model*, you'd want to be talking about rigid data; so if you were trying to represent *some number of* `N`, you should probably use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to evaluate the query and populate a list/array.

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested by Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975878/1663001), the problem is not with your Linq query, but rather it is in your MVC view. The error message you posted is telling you that your view (i.e. your `.cshtml` file) is expecting one type but you are passing into it another. It looks like you have made the common mistake of passing in an enumeration of values instead of a single value. Your solution is either:

- Pass in a single value to your view by using `Single()`, `First() etc.
- Fix your view so it takes `IEnumerable<T>` instead of just `T`, and update the code within to deal with that accordingly.